# cant get profile image and button image in custom listview

Tags: android

i am a beginner in android programming and i made a custom list view which should present the user details by searching function. while i search the the user i get only the name and the mobile of the user but the default images is not presenting.

this is what i get:

[image]

and this is what i would like to get:
[image]

this is the layout for the each row in the list:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffffff"
         >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/camera"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:text="Full name"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/profileImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/desc"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:text="User details"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageButtonInviteUser"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageButtonInviteUser"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title" />
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/add_user_50"
            android:id="@+id/imageButtonInviteUser"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:background="@drawable/border"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/profileImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextSearch"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Search..." />
    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
        android:id="@+id/scrollViewListView"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayoutBtn">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listViewusers"
            android:layout_below="@+id/divider1"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </ScrollView>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divider2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/scrollViewListView"

        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="6dp"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtn"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
        <Button android:text="Save"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">
        </Button>
        <Button android:text="Discard"
            android:id="@+id/ButtonDiscard"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ButtonSave"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1">

        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom adapter:

```
/**
 * Created by matant on 9/24/2015.
 */

import java.util.List;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.InviteUsersListRow;
import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;

public class InviteUsersArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<InviteUsersListRow> {

    Context context;
    List<InviteUsersListRow> rowUsers;

    public InviteUsersArrayAdapter(Context context,int resourceId, List<InviteUsersListRow> items) {
        super(context, resourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.rowUsers = items;
    }

    /*private view holder class*/
    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView txtTitle;
        TextView txtDesc;
        ImageButton imgStatus;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        InviteUsersListRow rowItem = (InviteUsersListRow) getItem(position);

        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.invite_users_listview_row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtDesc = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profileImage);
            holder.imgStatus = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonInviteUser);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        holder.txtDesc.setText(rowItem.getDesc());
        holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
        holder.imgStatus.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageStatus());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return rowUsers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public InviteUsersListRow getItem(int position) {
        return rowUsers.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return rowUsers.indexOf(getItem(position));
    }


}
```

row in list:

```
package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities;

/**
 * Created by matant on 9/22/2015.
 */
public class InviteUsersListRow {
    private int imageId,imagestatus;
    private  String title;
    private  String desc;

    public InviteUsersListRow(int imageId,int status, String title,String desc){
        this.imageId = imageId;
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.imagestatus = status;
    }

    public  int getImageId() {
        return this.imageId;
    }
    public void setImageId(int imageId) {
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }
    public  String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }
    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }
    public  String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public  int getImageStatus(){
        return this.imagestatus;
    }
    public void setImagestatus(int imgStatus)
    {
        this.imagestatus = imgStatus;
    }

}
```

main activity:

```
package com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Controllers;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.AsyncResponse;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.R;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.InviteUsersArrayAdapter;
import com.example.matant.gpsportclient.Utilities.InviteUsersListRow;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class InviteUsersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse, View.OnClickListener,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    private EditText editTextSearch;
    private Button btnSave,btnDiscard;
    private ListView usersListView;
    private List<InviteUsersListRow> rowUser;
    private DBcontroller dbController;
    public static final String EXTRA_USERS  = "";
    ListView listViewUsers;
    List<InviteUsersListRow> rowUsers;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_invite_users);

        editTextSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextSearch);
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSave);
        btnDiscard = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonDiscard);
        editTextSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                sendDataToDBController();

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
        btnDiscard.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void handleResponse(String resStr) {
        Log.d("invite_Response", resStr);
        if (resStr != null) {
            try {

                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(resStr);
                String flg = json.getString("flag");

                Log.d("flag",flg);
                switch (flg){

                    case "user found":{
                        JSONArray jsonarr = json.getJSONArray("users");
                        Log.d("array",jsonarr.toString());
                        rowUsers = new ArrayList<InviteUsersListRow>();
                        for(int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length();i++){
                            {
                                Log.d("user is", jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).toString());
                                String name = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
                                String mobile = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i).getString("mobile");
                                InviteUsersListRow rowUser = new InviteUsersListRow(R.id.profileImage, R.id.imageButtonInviteUser, name, mobile);
                                rowUsers.add(rowUser);
                            }
                            listViewUsers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewusers);
                            InviteUsersArrayAdapter Useradapter = new InviteUsersArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.invite_users_listview_row,rowUsers);
                            listViewUsers.setAdapter(Useradapter);
                            listViewUsers.setOnItemClickListener(this);
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else
             Log.d("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToDBController() {

        String username = editTextSearch.getText().toString();
        BasicNameValuePair tagreq = new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "search_user");
        BasicNameValuePair name = new BasicNameValuePair("name", username);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairList.add(tagreq);
        nameValuePairList.add(name);
        dbController = new DBcontroller(this,this);
        dbController.execute(nameValuePairList);

    }





    @Override
    public void preProcess() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.ButtonDiscard:
            {
                Intent i = new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED,i);;
                finish();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the below

InviteUsersListRow rowUser = new InviteUsersListRow(***R.id.profileImage, R.id.imageButtonInviteUser***, name, mobile);

with

InviteUsersListRow rowUser = new InviteUsersListRow(***R.drawable.camera, R.drawable.add_user_50***, name, mobile);

The pic should be from "R.drawable" not from "R.id"

You should actually set an image resource below and not an id

holder.imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageId());
holder.imgStatus.setImageResource(rowItem.getImageStatus());

In the above code you are not setting a drawable item.